# Salesforce Inbox and the action menu

Tags: quickaction, lightning-quickaction, inbox

I'm seeing that when logging into Salesforce through Salesforce Inbox in Outlook on the desktop, and the order of the Quick Create action menus are not the same. Inbox seems to show me some default quick menu which I can't edit through Setup -> Email -> Outlook Integration and Sync

[image: Inbox]

while the Quick Action menu in my Lightning environment shows me another set.

[image: Standard]

What controls the set of Quick Actions in Inbox?  I thought it used the same Lightning layout as the logged-in user?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the quick actions didn't appear in the Global menu.  The reason was simple, and something I had known before - if you have record types specified for the object created by the quick action, and you don't specify a record type in the quick action but let it default to the Master record type the action will not appear.  As soon as you specify a record type the Action will appear.